# Using Kerberos S4U extensions (introduced in Java 8) to connect to database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, java-8, kerberos

It's been a while since I coded in Java, so I may be missing something obvious. I want to connect to the database (I need to support many - SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) via JDBC. However, I want to use Microsoft S4U Java extension support that was added in Java 8 to achieve Kerberos delegation. I do not want the user to have to enter their credentials on my middle-tier server. I would like to use S4U to get a ticket for my middle-tier server on the user's behalf and use that to invoke the JDBC code via the doAs functions (Subject.doAs or doAsPrivileged).

I have added support for protocol transition and constrained delegation on Windows using C++ and ODBC. But I don't know how to do the same with Java. The S4U documentation on Java is sparse. This page seems to contain the most information - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/jgss-features.html. The page says "A new public method (GSSCredential::impersonate) has been added to the com.sun.security.jgss package to implement these extensions." Based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html, I was thinking that I need to use the classes LoginContext and Subject to invoke a doAs on a JDBC connection call so that the connection goes through under the Subject's credentials. But how do I use GSSCredential::impersonate in the mix?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I arrived at after a lot of spelunking online:

```
   GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
   GSSCredential self  = manager.createCredential(GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);
   GSSName user = manager.createName("myuser", GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
   GSSCredential impCred = ((ExtendedGSSCredential)self).impersonate(user);

   Subject mySubject = new Subject();
   mySubject.getPrivateCredentials().add(impCred);
   PrivilegedAction action = new ClientAction();
   Subject.doAs(mySubject, action);
```

I now get "GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Attempt to
obtain S4U2self credentials failed!)" on the impersonate call, which I am still investigating.

Comment: I was finally able to connect to the DB successfully using the code above. I had to delete the krbcc cache file from my user folder for the exception to go away. However, the connection goes through as the user logged into the machine and not the user I am trying to impersonate. So, the code for S4U2Self didn't really help.

Comment: Did you actually enable protocol transition and constrained delegation for the `self` account?

Comment: Yes. I am able to get protocol transition and constrained delegation working for the self account when I write code in C++ using Win32 API's and connect to the SQL Server db on the same machine. However, the Java code (with the SQL Server JDBC driver) is not doing Kerberos delegation for the same user. I see that S4U2SELF is going through fine and I am able to launch the PrivilegedAction as the delegated user, but the JDBC code is not honoring it and is instead just connecting to the db as the default principal.

Comment: That might be a shortcoming in the JDBC code of Microsoft. Did you try to create a ticket for the server manually with the impersonated context?

Comment: @user2237963 did you find anything on this? I am confused about the flags that need to be set on service user (who is impersonating the actual user).