# Kerberos S4U extension for JDBC connections

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, java-8, kerberos

Related with the question [Using Kerberos S4U extensions (introduced in Java 8) to connect to database using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377689/using-kerberos-s4u-extensions-introduced-in-java-8-to-connect-to-database-usin)

I am in the same scenario right now. According to Microsoft documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246071.aspx:

> The Kerberos Security Support Provider (SSP) will first detect whether
>   the forwarded-TGT delegation mechanism is available (by checking
>   whether there is a forwarded TGT in the local ticket cache); if no
>   forwarded TGT is available, the Kerberos SSP will then try to perform
>   the S4U2proxy delegation.

I remove the users TGT from the system cache and I am now facing a TGT not found error. Regarding the manually creation of a ticket for the server with the impersonated context, I am able to do that.

I reached this point using MS and JTDS drivers. It could be that the drivers are expecting a TGT but with the s4u2self mechanism we obtain a TGS?

Comment: Is your account trusted for protocol transition/constrained delegation?

Comment: Yes it is. I followed the next [intructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650469.aspx):  

Activate in the self account "Trust this user for delegation to specified services only" and "Use with any authentication protocol". Furthermore I added the SQL Server to the allowed services list.  

I am able to manually create a service ticket for the server with the impersonated context, so I think that configuraiton is ok.

Comment: @Michael-O any idea how to achieve impersonation in java when protocol transition is disabled ? In our customer side, "Use kerberos only" option is selected instead of "Use any authentication protocol". I am getting "S4U2.. requires a forwardable ticket".  Any help is highly appreciated.